# How can we automate the importing Prospects data in to Pardot

Tags: pardot

We want import the Prospect data in to the pardot without any manual interaction.
Is there any way to do the automate the data import process in pardot.
Please explain with steps/examples.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. API. See Pardot API documentation [here](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/prospects/#creating-prospects).
2. Adding Leads / Contacts automatically in Salesforce and then using the Pardot / Salesforce connector which the option to 'Automatically create prospects in Pardot if they are created as a Lead or Contact in salesforce.com'. See Salesforce connector documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_sf_connector_settings_reference.htm&type=5).